# Class has no initializers?

Tags: swift, class, init

I have been working at this for about an hour now. I've looked at other questions n this sight with the exact same error and I tried there solutions. I am still getting the error though. Here is my code:

```
class Links: UIViewController {

let firstLinkButton: UIButton?

let secondLinkButton: UIButton?


@IBAction func firstLinkButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)

}

@IBAction func secondLinkButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.bing.com")!)



}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

This is probably the simplest question on this sight today but any input or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S.: R.I.P. my reputation.

Comment: What's your problem exactly ?

Comment: I am getting an error "Class Link has no initializers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the buttons `var`

```
var firstLinkButton: UIButton?

var secondLinkButton: UIButton?
```

`let` constants must be initialized instantly.

Comment: WOW! Thanks. That fixed the problem.

Comment: You also probably want them to be `@IBAction` as it seems likely they're referenced from the nib/storyboard.